# Possible redundancy in a table generated by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

In my project, users can like a comment or a post, similar to Facebook likes. For this purpose, I created an abstract base class called Like keeping the if of the user who liked the post or the comment, and the datetime of the action. I have `CommentLike` class inheriting from `Like` class, which only have Comment property, and similarly, I have `PostLike` class inheriting from `Like` class, which only have Post property.

I use Entity Framework, and my database is generated successfully. In the generated database, there are CommentId, PostId, and Discriminator fields in the table. The thing is, if users like only one comment, and like only posts, then the CommentId field in the database will stay as null redundantly. I wonder if this is a problem. What if instead of these three fields, I only have one field, called RelatedItem which can indicate the associated Comment or the Post. In this case I can not define foreignkey I guess. Is this also a problem?

What would be best approach in such a situation?

```
public abstract class Like
{
    public int LikeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime WhenLiked { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("WhoLiked")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public Person WhoLiked { get; set; }
}

public class PostLike : Like
{
    [Required]
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Post")]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
}

public class CommentLike : Like
{
    [ForeignKey("Comment")]
    public int CommentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the database generated:

[image]

Comment: For this as the entities are simple I would probably go with the table per concrete class. There doesn't seem much benefit in having the 'parent' table in a table per type approach.

Comment: Take a read through [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) which explains the different approaches.

Comment: That is the trade-off when using the TPH (table per hierarchy) strategy. There are other inheritance techniques with the FK usage that you outline with its own trade-offs.